# Extract one column of csv into a comma separated list python

Tags: python, csv, split, strip

I have a CSV file that I read like below:

```
with open ("ann.csv", "rb") as annotate:
    for col in annotate:
        ann = col.lower().split(",")
        print ann[0]
```

My CSV file looks like below:

```
H1,H2,H3
da,ta,one
dat,a,two
```

My output looks like this:

```
da
dat
```

but I want a comma separated output like (da,dat). How can I do that?

Comment: You mean you want them in one line and separated by comma?

Comment: @m170897017 Exactly!

Comment: Your script will actually output `H1<newline>da<newline>dat` - do you want to skip headers or not?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I do. Your answer worked great for me. Thank you. Will accept it a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in Python you have the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) - use that.

Second, you're iterating through rows, so using `col` as a variable name is a bit confusing.

Third, just collect the items in a list and print that using `.join()`:

```
import csv
with open ("ann.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next() # Skip the header row
    collected = []
    for row in reader:
        collected.append(row[0])
    print ",".join(collected)
```

Comment: @Li-aungYip: Thanks for adding the comma, I forgot.

Comment: No problem. And +1 for use of the `csv` module instead of `split(',')` which doesn't allow for the possibility of comma literals in the data.

Answer (score 3):

try like this:

```
with open ("ann.csv", "rb") as annotate:
    output = []
    next(annotate)    # next will advanced the file pointer to next line
    for col in annotate:
        output.append(col.lower().split(",")[0])
    print ",".join(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing it on the spot, build up a string, and print it in the end.

```
s = ''
with open ("ann.csv", "rb") as annotate:
    for col in annotate:
        ann = col.lower().split(",")
        s += ann[0] + ','
s = s[:-1] # Remove last comma
print(s)
```

I would also suggest to change the variable name `col`, it is looping over lines, not over columns.

Comment: Typo. Last += should be a +. I have changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Then try this:

```
result = ''
with open ("ann.csv", "rb") as annotate:
    for col in annotate:
        ann = col.lower().split(",")
        # add first element of every line to one string and separate them by comma
        result = result + ann[0] + ','

print result
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
>>> with open ("ann.csv", "rb") as annotate:
...     for col in annotate:
...         ann = col.lower().split(",")
...         print ann[0]+',',
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) might be a bit easier:

```
In [23]: import numpy as np
    ...: fn = 'a.csv'
    ...: m = np.loadtxt(fn, dtype=str, delimiter=',')
    ...: print m
[['H1' 'H2' 'H3']
 ['da' 'ta' 'one']
 ['dat' 'a' 'two']]

In [24]: m[:,0][1:]
Out[24]: 
array(['da', 'dat'], 
      dtype='|S3')

In [25]: print ','.join(m[:,0][1:])
da,dat
```

`m[:,0]` gets the first column of matrix `m`, and `[1:]` skips the first element `'H1'`.